# Renaming a list of files from a text file

Tags: scripting, rename

I have a folder containing these list of files.

```
lesson1.mp4
lesson2.mp4
lesson3.mp4
lesson4.mp4
```

I`m trying to rename this files based on contents of "rename.txt"

```
 1. Introduction to the React Ecosystem Video 
 2. Video Babel, Webpack, and React 
 3. Solution - Props 
 4. Solution - .map and .filter
```

I`m running this script

```
for file in *.mp4; 
do read line;  
mv -v "${file}" "${line}";  
done < rename.txt
```

which gives me unwanted results

```
'lesson1.mp4' -> '1. Introduction to the React Ecosystem Video '
'lesson10.mp4' -> '2. Video Babel, Webpack, and React '
'lesson11.mp4' -> '3. Solution - Props '
'lesson12.mp4' -> '4. Solution - .map and .filter '
'lesson13.mp4' -> '5. Video Validating Components with PropTypes'
```

Wanted Results.

```
'lesson1.mp4' -> '1. Introduction to the React Ecosystem Video.mp4'
'lesson2.mp4' -> '2. Video Babel, Webpack, and React.mp4'
'lesson3.mp4' -> '3. Solution - Props.mp4'
'lesson4.mp4' -> '4. Solution - .map and .filter.mp4'
'lesson5.mp4' -> '5. Video Validating Components with PropTypes.mp4'
```

Comment: post **wanted** results

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry, my bad. I`ve edited my question.

Comment: are you sure you want to leave all the files without extension?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No. Well, I didn`t think about that.

Comment: yes, think about that and if needed - edit your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Done

Comment: but your `rename.txt` may not contain a replacement equivalent for `lesson10.mp4`. How such event should be treated?

Comment: Actually, there is exactly 1-1 matching with the contents in the text file with the video files. Such event won`t occur. 

Example: lesson10.mp4 does have an equivalent in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell expansion instead of globbing:

```
for file in lesson{1..10}.mp4;do
       read line
       mv -v "${file}" "${line}"
done < rename.txt
```

Although this seems quite error prone, if you have lots of files you need to do this with you could look at matching the number in the filename with the number at the beginning of the the line in the rename file. Something like:

```
for file in *.mp4;do
       num=$(echo "${file}" | sed -E 's/^lesson([0-9]+).mp4$/\1/')
       line=$(grep -E "^ *${num}\." rename.txt)
       mv -v "${file}" "${line}"
done
```

This way it shouldn't matter what order the `rename.txt` file is in, and it does not matter which order the shell globs the filenames in.

Comment: I copied your second program and ran "sh rename.sh" but it yields the following error.  
      'lesson1.mp4' -> ''
       mv: cannot move 'lesson1.mp4' to '': No such file or directory
       'lesson10.mp4' -> '' 
       mv: cannot move 'lesson10.mp4' to '': No such file or directory
      'lesson11.mp4' -> ''

Comment: I've modified and tested the above script, it was more of a suggestion of the way you could do it. You'd probably want to check the `line` variable is actually set before running `mv`. I think you have spaces at the beginning of `rename.txt`, which is why `line` was empty.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the `-v` option of `ls` to guarantee proper numeric sorting of the file list. Each file name is put in a shell positional parameter. To guarantee that a full file name is put in each parameter, it temporarily changes the shell's 'internal field separator' so that if you ever end up having file names with embedded spaces, it will still work. Finally, because I hate file names with embedded spaces (and you would do well to develop a similar instinct), it converts all embedded spaces to underscores. The `shift` command just pops the values of all positional parameters forward, so `$1` gets the next value in the list.

```
oldifs="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'
set $(ls -v1 lesson*)
while read line ; do
  mv "$1" "${line// /_}"
  shift
done < rename.txt
IFS="${oldifs}"
```